# Rigorous derivation of Faraday's induction

Tags: electromagnetism, fluid-dynamics, integration, magnetohydrodynamics

When deriving Faraday's law of induction, one needs to calculate the time derivative of the flux $\Phi = \int_{S(t)} \vec{B} \cdot \vec{n} \;dS$, where $S(t)$ is the surface over which we define this flux. Now, Jackson and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfv%C3%A9n%27s_Theorem) (see first equation) state that it is easy to prove that
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{S(t)} \vec{B} \cdot \vec{n} \;dS = \int_{S(t)} \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} \cdot \vec{n}\;dS + \oint_{\partial S(t)} \vec{B} \cdot \vec{v} \times d\vec{l},$$
where I assume $\vec{v}(t,\vec{x})$ is the vector field describing the velocity of the surface $S(t)$.

I fail to see how the second term is obvious and how I could get it from straightforward differentiation, no drawings.

My first idea would be to use that this is in fact a material derivative, and so the second term should come from $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{\nabla} \vec{B}$ plus some kind of Stoke's theorem. Is that possible?

Comment: This topic seems to be very popular at the moment.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction#Proof_of_Faraday.27s_law

Comment: May be useful to take a look here : http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/189924/why-the-induced-field-is-ignored-in-faradays-law
my answer as user82794, where the Helmholtz transport  theorem is used

Answer (score 1):

So, let's take some closed loop enclosing a surface $S$ within the fluid and see how the magnetic flux through that loop changes as the loop gets carried along by the fluid. Over a time interval $dt$, $S$ moves a distance $\vec{v} \cdot dt$ and ends up as $S'$. The change in the flux is

$$d\Phi=\int_{S'} \vec{B}(t+dt) \cdot d\vec{a} \; - \int_{S} \vec{B}(t) \cdot d\vec{a} \;$$

Now, since $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{B} = 0$ always, we can integrate $\vec B(t+dt)$ over the closed surface formed by the three surfaces $-S$, $S'$ and $R$ (the surface between $S$ and $S'$) taken together, then use the divergence theorem (this might be the "kind of Stoke's theorem" you were thinking of) to obtain

$$\int_{V} \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{B}d^3\vec{r} \; = \int_{S'} \vec{B}(t+dt) \cdot d\vec{a} \; + \int_{R} \vec{B}(t+dt) \cdot d\vec{a} \; - \int_{S} \vec{B}(t+dt) \cdot d\vec{a} = 0\;$$

($V$ is the volume enclosed by the three surfaces). Then, our preceding equation becomes

$$d\Phi=\int_{S} \vec{B}(t+dt) \cdot d\vec{a} \; - \int_{S} \vec{B}(t) \cdot d\vec{a} \; - \int_{R} \vec{B}(t+dt) \cdot d\vec{a} \; = dt\int_{S} \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} \cdot d\vec{a} \; - \int_{R} \vec{B}(t+dt) \cdot d\vec{a} \; $$

The differential area $d\vec{a}$ is a parallelogram bounded by a line element $d\vec{l}$ around the loop $\partial S$ and the distance vector $\vec{v} \cdot dt$, so

$$d\vec{a}=d\vec{l} \times \vec{v} \cdot dt$$

Meaning that integrating over $d\vec{a}$ is equivalent to adding up these area elements as we move around the loop. That is, our second term becomes

$$ \int_{R} \vec{B}(t+dt) \cdot d\vec{a} \; = \oint_{\partial S} \vec{B} (t+dt) \cdot (d\vec{l} \times \vec{v} \cdot dt) = dt \oint_{\partial S} \vec{B} (t) \cdot (d\vec{l} \times \vec{v})$$

Where I have taken a first order approximation in the last step. Finally, after some arrangement, we recover the expression you were asking for:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\Phi=\int_{S} \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} \cdot d\vec{a}\; + \oint_{\partial S} \vec{B} (t) \cdot (\vec{v} \times d\vec{l})$$

Interestingly enough, and since you asked, Alfvén's theorem can be interpreted in terms of material curves, and the ideal induction equation can be written as a material derivative. See [this notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/gio10/afd_notes.pdf) for more details (section 2.1: *Physical interpretation of MHD*). Also, notice the resemblance between Alfvén's and [Kevin's circulation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin%27s_circulation_theorem) in inviscid fluid dynamics.

Comment: A nice answer; same approach was taken by Purcell in his book.